# "Add some technologies you like" link doesn't link correctly

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

On the careers site when viewing your profile there are a few links on the right prompting you to fill in details you've not filled in already.

One of these is "Add some technologies you like", which doesn't link correctly. The issue appears to be that it's expecting a div with id `cv-technologies` but the div actually has an id of just `technologies`.

I guess while minor, it should be fixed.

Comment: Reproduced, same problem is in the "Completeness Score" page. Guess the ID of the div was changed at some point and those links missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug has been fixed.

As pointed by @ShadowWizard, the completeness score page had a similar issue. It has been fixed as well.

Thank you for the report !